# time delay after printing lines with sed or awk in large file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, timedelay

I have a large file (1Gb) and I need to extract a few lines of it using the record number. I wrote my script with sed and, as it took too much time, I decided to investigate it.
It turns out that, when I run something like
sed -n '15689,15696p' filename
the print is quick, but I have a time delay after it, and this is turning my script really slow. Doing the same task with awk the delay is smaller, but it's still there! The command line I used for awk was:
awk 'NR>=15689 && NR<=15696' filename

I tried to print just one line (sed -n '15689p' filename) and the same problem appears!

I'm wondering if no one has ever seen that before and knows how to get rid of this stupid delay. It seems to me this is a big problem, because this delay occurs after the printing task! I already searched in this and in other forums and I haven't seen a question with this issue.
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: If you tell `awk` to 'exit' after printing the line you want does that help? `awk` (and `sed`) don't know that they are done unless you tell them to finish/exit. If you don't they still need to loop over the rest of the file.

Comment: i think it may reduce the time `awk 'NR==15689{print; exit}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using `sed -n '15689,15696p'`, as sed will go through the entire file. The fastest way I know is this:

```
head -15696 filename | tail -10
```

I benchmarked it, and it runs way faster:

```
$ seq 1 100000000 > file

$ time (head -50000000 file | tail -10) > /dev/null
real    0m0.694s
user    0m0.830s
sys     0m0.333s

$ time (sed -n '49999991,50000000p' file) > /dev/null
real    0m6.018s
user    0m5.863s
sys     0m0.160s

$ time (sed -n '50000000q;49999991,50000000p' file) > /dev/null
real    0m3.197s
user    0m3.153s
sys     0m0.043s

$ time (awk 'NR>=49999991 && NR<=50000000' file) > /dev/null
real    0m12.665s
user    0m12.543s
sys     0m0.123s

$ time (awk 'NR>=49999991 && NR<=50000000{print} NR==50000001{exit}' file)
real    0m9.104s
user    0m9.010s
sys     0m0.100s
```

Comment: Perfect! I loved this solution, but the number of lines is not always the same for me and, perhaps, recording this also as the record numbers will expend more time than using awk. But, I'll try both and see whats fits best for me! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Just adding one more comment.... why sed goes through the entire file if he already completed the task I asked him? This really makes no sense at all.... =/

Answer (score 3):

It's because it scans right to the end of the file. Try this to quit after printing:

```
sed -ne '15690q;15689p' file
```

Or with awk:

```
awk 'NR>=15689 && NR<=15696{print} NR==15697{exit}' filename
```

Just for kicks, I ran @RichardHum 's timings and mine are totally the opposite on OSX Mavericks with a SSD drive:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
seq 1 100000000 > file
time (head -50000000 file | tail -10) > /dev/null
time (sed -n '50000000q;49999991,50000000p' file) > /dev/null
time (awk 'NR>=49999991 && NR<=50000000{print} NR==50000001{exit}' file)
time (head -50000000 file | tail -10) > /dev/null
```

and I got:

```
time (head -50000000 file | tail -10) > /dev/null
real    0m29.565s
user    0m35.711s
sys 0m0.733s

time (sed -n '50000000q;49999991,50000000p' file) > /dev/null
real    0m13.313s
user    0m13.162s
sys 0m0.150s

time (awk 'NR>=49999991 && NR<=50000000{print} NR==50000001{exit}' file)
real    0m7.433s
user    0m7.293s
sys 0m0.139s

time (head -50000000 file | tail -10) > /dev/null
real    0m29.560s
user    0m35.697s
sys 0m0.742s
```

I even ran the head+tail solution at the end in case it had no benefit of caching the first time but it is definitely miles slower!

Comment: Thanks! The first code only worked with me for one line, so it's not good for me. But the second works really well! =)

Comment: Are any of your `head`, `tail`, `sed`, and `awk` the GNU versions or those that are shipped by Apple?

Comment: I think I used `GNU awk` and the rest were Apple supplied.